# How to solve the following limits?

Tags: limits

1.$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n+2}\right)$

2.$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n+2}-2\sqrt{n+3}\right)$

Thanks for help

Comment: See also: [Limit of : $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{(\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n})}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3434089)

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{(\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n+2})}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{(\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n+2})}\left(\frac{(n+1)^{2/3}+\sqrt[3]{(n+1)(n+2)}+(n+2)^{2/3}}{(n+1)^{2/3}+\sqrt[3]{(n+1)(n+2)}+(n+2)^{2/3}}\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{(\sqrt[3]{n+1})^3-(\sqrt[3]{n+2})^3}{(n+1)^{2/3}+\sqrt[3]{(n+1)(n+2)}+(n+2)^{2/3}}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{-1}{(n+1)^{2/3}+\sqrt[3]{(n+1)(n+2)}+(n+2)^{2/3}}}$$ as the sequence under the division line diverges to $\infty$ we can say that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{(\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n+2})}=0$

Comment: So I'll be trying this for the second problem... and I'll hope I'll finish within a reasonable amount of time... but then I just realized all this is hopelessly messy and I gave up.

Comment: you can use the suggestion of @Bernard and this could be faster than the algebraic method. Good luck!

Comment: The conjugate quantity is incorrect, please use $(n+1)^{2/3}$ and $(n+2)^{2/3}$ instead of $(n+1)$ and $(n+2)$.

Comment: Thank's, I've made that mistake before... really thanks by the apointment.

Answer (score 2):

*Taylor's formula* at order $1$ will do it: \begin{align}\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n+2}&=\sqrt[3]n\biggl(\sqrt[3]{1+\dfrac1n}-\sqrt[3]{1+\dfrac2n}\biggr)\\&=\sqrt[3]n\biggl(1+\dfrac1{3n}+o\Bigl(\dfrac1n\Bigr)-1-\dfrac2{3n}+o\Bigl(\dfrac1n\Bigr)\biggr) \\
&=-\frac1{3\sqrt[3]{n^2}}+o\biggl(\dfrac1{\sqrt[3]{n^2}}\biggr)\to 0
\end{align}

Same method for the second limit.

Comment: The prefactor should be $\sqrt[3]{n}$, not $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: @Did: Yes. I probably was tired to type all those root orders. Thanks for pointing it. I'll fix it in a moment.

Comment: Another option (especially if you are tired) would be to avoid answering questions that are multi duplicates without personal input, which mainly pollute the site, and to concentrate on the good questions, which too often go unnoticed due to the sheer volume of the other category of questions...