# Limit of : $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{(\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n})}$.

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

I have to find $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{(\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n})}$$
here what I did $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{(\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n})}$$=$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left(\sqrt[3]{n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}-\sqrt[3]{n}\right)}$$
How can I proceed?

Comment: Rationalize the numerator using $$a^3-b^3$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{(\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n})}$$$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)-n}{(n+1)^{\frac{2}{3}}+(n+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}n^{\frac{1}{3}}+n^{\frac{2}{3}}}$$$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^{\frac{2}{3}}+(n+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}n^{\frac{1}{3}}+n^{\frac{2}{3}}}$$$$=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to consider
$$
f(x)=\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+x^3}-1}{x}
$$
so your limit is
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f(1/\sqrt[3]{n})
$$
and you solve the problem if you find that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}f(x)
$$
exists, because your limit would be the same. This limit is much easier:
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+x^3}-1}{x}
$$
is the derivative at $0$ of $g(x)=\sqrt[3]{1+x^3}$; since
$$
g'(x)=\dfrac{3x^2}{3\sqrt[3]{(1+x^3)^2}}
$$
we have $g'(0)=0$. So you conclude that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigl({\textstyle\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n}}\bigr)=0
$$

How did I find $f$? Just formally substituting $n=1/x^3$.

Answer (score 1):

$(1+1/n)^{1/3} \le 1+(1/3)(1/n)$ (Bernouilli inequality)

$0<n^{1/3}((1+1/n)^{1/3}-1) \le$

$n^{1/3}(1/3)(1/n)\le n^{-2/3}$.

Squeeze.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$\left(m+\frac1{3m^2}\right)^3=m^3+1+\frac1{3m^3}+\frac1{27m^6}>m^3+1$$

so that

$$m<\sqrt[3]{m^3+1}<m+\frac1{3m^2}$$ and by letting $n=m^3$, the requested limit squeezes to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

You may Taylor-expand

$$\sqrt[3]{n \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}-\sqrt[3]{n}=\sqrt[3]{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1/3}- \sqrt[3]{n}=\sqrt[3]{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{3n}\right)- \sqrt[3]{n}
=\frac{\sqrt[3]{n}}{3n}$$

and then take the limit to get zero.

Comment: How did you get (1+1/3n)?

Comment: @Sandro Jologua - Let $f(x)=(1+x)^{1/3},\>f’(x)=\frac13(1+x)^{-2/3}$. Then, with $x=\frac1n$,  $(1+1/n)^{1/3}=f(1)+f’(1)\frac1n=1+\frac 13 \frac 1n$.

Answer (score 0):

By binomial approximation

$$\sqrt[3]{n+1}=\sqrt[3]n\left(1+\frac1n\right)^\frac13\approx \sqrt[3]n\left(1+\frac1{3n}\right)=\sqrt[3]n+\frac{\sqrt[3]n}{3n}$$

therefore

$$\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n}\approx \sqrt[3]n+\frac{\sqrt[3]n}{3n}-\sqrt[3]n=\frac{\sqrt[3]n}{3n} \to 0$$